# How to move a set of nodes without modifying each coordinates?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following is a trivial example to illustrate my problem.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,4) -- (5,4);
    \tikzset{anchor=south west}
    % header
    \node at (0,3) {Name};
    \node at (2,3) {Address};
    % item 1
    \node at (0,2) {John};
    \node at (2,2) {California};
    % item 2
    \node at (0,1) {Marry};
    \node at (2,1) {Munich};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Constraints

- I  want to move all item nodes several unit up.
- I don't want to modify each node given above because there are many items.

### Question

How to move all nodes, for example, `3mm` up?

Comment: With respect to the line? Or the baseline of the picture?

Comment: `\tikzset{every node/.append style={yshift=3mm}}`. Or `\begin{scope}[yshift=3mm] ... \end{scope}`.

Comment: Put everything except the line in `\begin{scope}[yshift=3mm]...\end{scope}`. Or my preference, bring the line 3mm down.

Comment: Are you threatening us? :P I couldn't find a duplicate

Comment: @percusse: How to make "Marry" and "Munich"  have the same baseline?

Comment: It seems to me that if you move *all* the nodes, then the visual effect will be nullified.  It might help if you could give us an example which illustrates how this will result in a different appearance.  Or, could you compare this something that you would do in `pstricks` so we could better understand what you're asking for (such as perhaps `\pstTranslation{A}{B}{M1,M2,...,Mn}[M1',M2',...,Mn']`

Comment: To make "Marry" and "Munich" have the same baseline, you have to adjust the `text depth` since Marry has `y` :D. Put `text depth=0.5ex` as the `tikzpicture` option or `\tikzset{every node/.append style={text depth=0.5ex}}`

Comment: Another way of aligning the base lines would be to use `anchor=base west`. Unless there is a specific reason for `anchor=south west` in the MWE (e.g., the nodes are going to be filled/drawn and it is the bottom edge of the node paths that need to be aligned).

Comment: @A.Ellett: Visual effect will not be nullified because I am overlaying some texts on the blank spaces of a PDF form. The lines and other texts on the form can be regarded as the inertial frame of reference to which the item nodes are approaching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having read the comments given above, I realize the comments are useful and should be converted to an answer to finalize the problem.

**Jake**'s comment:

```
\tikzset{every node/.append style={yshift=3mm}}
```

Or

```
\begin{scope}[yshift=3mm] ... \end{scope}
```

**Mark Wibrow**'s comment:

One way for aligning the base lines would be to use `anchor=base west`.